# Minor change cause HighStock charts syncing to fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I am trying to modify this HighStock example: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/synchronized-charts

I have made a really small change which you can see in this JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/fshsweden/zyzdzk3j/

Basically, instead of adding all charts on top of each other into #container, I want each chart in his own #chart_1, #chart_2 etc etc like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="chart_1"></div>
    <div id="chart_2"></div>
    <div id="chart_3"></div>
</div>
```

In order to do this, I made a small change in loading and changed this

```
$('<div class="chart">')
.appendTo('#container')
.highcharts({
```

into

```
Highcharts.stockChart('chart_' + count, {
```

The charts end up in the right place, but the synchronization code

```
($('#container').bind('mousemove touchmove touchstart', function (e) {
```

no longer work (the highlight bar isnt synchronized between the charts). Can anyone explain why that is so?

Thanks
Peter

Comment: `this.series.chart.tooltip.refresh(this); // Show the tooltip` creates problem comment this and check   https://jsfiddle.net/4um9ghvq/ and also check this  [post](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5461)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Deep3015 says, this was the short answer:

this.series.chart.tooltip.refresh(this); // Show the tooltip creates problem comment this and check jsfiddle.net/4um9ghvq and also check this post – Deep 3015

Kamil Kuligs anser is probably right too, but I don't understand it fully...

Answer (score 0):

All these errors occur (check out the console output), because the example that you referred to:

> I am trying to modify this HighStock example: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/synchronized-charts

is adjusted for **Highcharts** (`Highcharts.chart()`) and not for **Highstock** (`Highcharts.stockChart()`).

If you change the library to `highcharts.js` and the constructor to the `Highcharts.chart()` your code will work just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/b41xxutj/

I've done some adjustments to make it work in Highstock too: https://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/rnv2ovru/
All changes in `Tooltip.prototype.refresh` function are marked with comment: `//adjustment for Highstock`.